# How to configure my bash_profile to execute ipython3

Tags: python

I'm using Anaconda 2 and Anaconda 3 in my Mac X OS. I need open the notebook from python3 (Anaconda 3). I use this command: "ipython notebook" on the terminal to open notebook from Python 2.

Can someone help me to configure bash_profile or a different way to open the notebook from Py3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could do that.

You can put the Anaconda3 first in the path:

```
PATH=/path/to/anaconda3:$PATH
```

Or make an alias:

```
alias ipython='ipython3'
alias ipython2='ipython'
```

*Assuming ipython3 is in the path somehow*

Comment: I have not ipython3 in bash profile. How can i put it ?

Comment: Just add the alias lines at the end of your .bash_profile and restart your bash. Now when you type ipython it will start ipython3

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my bash_profile:

```
# Python
alias py2="/Users/andres.vara/Python/Anaconda2/anaconda/bin/python"
alias pip2="/Users/andres.vara/Python/Anaconda2/anaconda/bin/pip"
alias py3="/Users/andres.vara/Python/Anaconda3/anaconda/bin/python"
alias pip3="/Users/andres.vara/Python/Anaconda3/anaconda/bin/pip"


# export PATH="/Users/andres.vara/Python/Anaconda3/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/andres.vara/Python/Anaconda2/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```